# C++ If Then Won't Work/Stop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, arduino

I am trying to make a simple Arduino code for when a photocell reading is less than 900, it will add 1 to the CurrentNumber and display it on a 4 digit 7 segment display. The problem is that it wont stop adding one even though it's reading more than 1000.

```
void loop() {
 photocellReading = analogRead(photocellPin);  
 Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
 Serial.println(photocellReading);    // the raw analog reading
 photocellReading = 1023 - photocellReading;

 if(photocellReading << 10){
 CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1;
 }

 displayNumber(CurrentNumber);
}
```

Comment: `if(photocellReading << 10){` This line is suspicious to me. Youre shifting the bits to the left by 10 essentially multiplying by 2^10. Is this intended?

Comment: I don't understand your description.  But I'm pretty sure you want `<`, not `<<`.

Comment: What is the type of `photocellReading`?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is in your if condition:

```
 if(photocellReading << 10){
     CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1;
 }
```

What you're essentially doing he is: shifting the bits of photocellReading to the left by 10 (which is equivalent to multiplying by 2^10 aka 1024). *Most likely* this means the only time this is ever going to be false is if the value of photocellReading was 0 to start with. (I say most likely because it depends on if the bits loop back around or not, but this is not entirely relevant).

tl;dr your code is *conceptually* equivalent to:

```
if((photocellReading * 1024) != 0){
    CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1;
}
```

What I'm guessing you wanted to do (considering you subtracted 1023, which coincidentally is 1024 - 1) is:

```
if(photocellReading < 1024){ // again 1024 == 2^10
    CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1;
}
```

Comment: Conceptually speaking, yes, it would be equivalent to that, but there's one other side effect: If the lesser 22 bits are 0, the expression will evaluate to false (but given the possible values of that variable, this should never happen)

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Thanks for pointing that out, I made a small edit to clarify the situation.